# Consistency level Quorum vs One for reads after Inserts

Tags: cassandra, consistency

I have an application that perform only inserts/deletes in cassandra. All write operations (inserts/deletes) application perform using consistency level QUORUM, read operation currently is executed using QUORUM as well, but i`m wondering if in this case (when there is no updates to data) consistency level ONE would give same results as QUORUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.  It could be that your read request goes to the *one* node which has not (yet) received/applied the updates.  The `QUORUM` consistency level does allow for some nodes to not have the updated data just yet; by using a consistency level of `ONE` for your read, you might read stale data.  Perhaps your application can deal with this situation -- that's for you to decide.  But you should know that a consistency level of `ONE` for reads *may not* return the data you expect in your situation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer, is there no guarantee even if we use TokenAwarePolicy load balancing policy? I though in this case query is always sent to nodes which should have requested keys.

Comment: The query will be sent to the nodes which _should_ have the requested keys (based on the hashing-- but again, it's a race condition, between the update and the read.  Using the `TokenAwarePolicy` decreases the chances, on a read using consistency level `ONE`, that you'll get a stale read -- but does not prevent it entirely.

Comment: I should also point out that if you are thinking of having multiple "data centers" in your Cassandra configuration, you will probably want to use the `LOCAL_QUORUM` consistency level, rather than `QUORUM`; the latter enforces quorum _across datacenters_, which can add undesirable latency  (or maybe that's the behavior you need?); it's a small gotcha to be aware of.